# Xamarin.Forms iOS release build crashes at startup

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am having major issues with Xamarin. I am using Xamarin.Forms and it works fine for Android, but for iOS build it works perfectly in Debug, but when I do a release build the app crashes at the startup. Here are some logs I was able to capture:

```
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Found new TLS offset at 224
Error (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS(UIKit): The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Mac' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Mac' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Deprecated' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Deprecated' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Mobile' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Akavache.Mobile' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: VideoPlayer [INFO]: Initializing Xamarin Forms Video Player on iPhone v10.3.2
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS(AppleJPEG): [0x1057e8600] Created session
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'ReactiveUI.XamForms' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'ReactiveUI.XamForms' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'ReactiveUI.Winforms' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'ReactiveUI.Winforms' (culture: '')
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: [Error] CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: Unhandled managed exception:
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical: Stacktrace:
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  0   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c0facc WebPGetDecoderVersion + 323252
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018cbb131c _sigtramp + 52
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018cbb7264 pthread_kill + 112
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000018ca619c4 abort + 140
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  4   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103d46d28 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 4588
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  5   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c557f4 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 609244
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  6   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c0f5cc WebPGetDecoderVersion + 321972
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  7   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c0e5f0 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 317912
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  8   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c06580 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 285032
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  9   BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000100775798 sqlite3_db_readonly + 6676600
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  10  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x00000001005103fc sqlite3_db_readonly + 4164828
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  11  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000100513ae4 sqlite3_db_readonly + 4178884
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  12  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000101fef498 sqlite3_db_readonly + 32341368
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  13  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x00000001019da454 sqlite3_db_readonly + 25963828
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  14  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x000000010071bcd4 sqlite3_db_readonly + 6309300
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  15  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c1e6a8 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 383632
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  16  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c9843c WebPGetDecoderVersion + 882724
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  17  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c98398 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 882560
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  18  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103b33be4 sqlite3_db_readonly + 60933316
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  19  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103b3aa3c sqlite3_db_readonly + 60961564
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  20  Foundation                          0x000000018e5e64cc <redacted> + 340
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018daa142c <redacted> + 24
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018daa0d04 <redacted> + 388
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018da9e9a8 <redacted> + 744
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d9ceda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018f438074 GSEventRunModal + 100
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  26  UIKit                               0x0000000193c89058 UIApplicationMain + 208
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  27  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000102270f64 sqlite3_db_readonly + 34969668
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  28  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000101bbbfcc sqlite3_db_readonly + 27936940
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  29  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000101bbbe8c sqlite3_db_readonly + 27936620
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  30  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x00000001001ff554 sqlite3_db_readonly + 949812
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  31  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x000000010071bcd4 sqlite3_db_readonly + 6309300
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  32  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c1e6a8 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 383632
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  33  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c9843c WebPGetDecoderVersion + 882724
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  34  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c9b660 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 895560
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  35  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103c02f04 WebPGetDecoderVersion + 271084
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  36  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103d4b8f0 xamarin_localized_string_format_9 + 3196
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  37  BrixnMobileUIiOS                    0x0000000103bbc530 sqlite3_db_readonly + 61492752
Info (11667) / BrixnMobileUIiOS: critical:  38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018c9dd59c <redacted> + 4
```

Regarding "The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.", I did put UIWindow Window override and it removed that warning but crash still occurs.

I can see it also complains about some assemblies, but I either don't use those or they are present. My linker option is set to "Don't Link". In debug everything runs fine without any problems. I am really lost here....

Comment: Can you share what is the reference packages in your PCL/Forms project and iOS UI project.

Comment: @lowleetak it is a pretty long list. Are there any specific ones you want me to show?

Comment: Just to make sure is the packages added in PCL project is also added into iOS UI Project?

Comment: They are all there, in fact iOS has more references. I double checked all that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you change linker option to "SDK assembly only".
2. Look if there is anything wrong inside #if RELEASE #endif phrase.

Comment: 1. I will try that, I doubt it will fix it, as I think I have tried all options for the linker. 2. I don't think I have any pragma statements anywhere, but I will check